# How to burn an iso to a bootable sd card? (Not Ubuntu)

Tags: mount, iso

I have an iso image of Windows 8 which I would like to burn to an sd card. How do I do this?  I know about the startup disk creator but it only works for an ubuntu image.

Answer (score 0):

Each operating system works differently, specially if talking about windows-linux. Thus, id recommend you to use the microsoft tool. Although i haven't tried it, I read that the windows 7 USB tool will do the job, check out this post for more information:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1263664

Comment: I'm on ubnutu. Hence the ubuntu forum

Comment: i think that it'll be much easier to borrow a windows machine to do the usb than to do it in ubuntu. windows and ubuntu dont play well